# How to create a rotation animation with "Manipulate Centre Points" turned on?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm trying to create an animation of an object rotating around a center point. By setting the 3D cursor a distance from the object, turning "Manipulate Centre Points" on and rotating freely, the rotation works just as a I want. For example:

[image]

The problem I'm having is when I try to animate this. When I rotate the object and try to set a "rotation" key frame, the rotation doesn't work. I think this is because "Manipulate Centre Points" does not actually change the rotation, only the location:

[image]

I've managed to create a work-around by rotating the object small amounts, then  creating "location" keyframes for each step. But this an approximation of the rotation, because the object is actually moving in a straight line between keyframes rather than in a true circle. Is there a better/easier way to do this?

Edit: Omar Ahmad, Xtremity & PGmath's answers below all work perfectly. PGMath has some animated GIFs in the answer, for which I clicked "accept".

Comment: I must learn how to do animated gifs!

Comment: @Xtremity - http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/963/935

Comment: Perfect - I was looking for a way to create animated gifs too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by parenting the object to an empty and using rotation constraints.

First add an [empty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45849/5705) at the point you want the object to rotate around.  Then select the object and then the empty (in that order) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent it to the empty.  Now you can animate the empty revolving around as desired.

[image]

Then select the object and go to the *Constraints* Properties panel and add a *Limit Rotation* constraint and enable the constraint on all three axes, leaving the *Min* and *Max* values at `0`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use **"Follow Path Constraint"**.

Add a circle curve,then select the object and add the **Follow Path**.

Press Animate Path and check follow curve if needed,and play the animation.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add an Empty to the scene at the origin.  Set Suzanne's parent to the Empty by selecting Suzanne, then the Empty then pressing <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>.  Rotating the empty should now rotate Suzanne about the origin.  However, the monkey turns to face the origin which isn't desired.
[image]
Now add a Limit Rotation constraint to the Suzanne object.  Enable Z-axis, plus any others you need.  When you rotate the empty, Suzanne will keep facing south.
[image]