# How to control the visibility of many planes with a single material and different images

Tags: texturing, visibility

I am rather new in blender - (max and maya before) And I would like to create lets say a 50 planes with the same material but with a different image source file. And then, joint every plane´s "visibility" to controller.

So, if I set 1 on slider then i will see only first plane, 2 - second etc.

My problem is I dont fully understand, where can I find some kind of this "visibility" for objects - or whole opacity. (where I would like to set some expressions). And Of course best is some kind of material solution, where i only change number of input - but as I said, i dond know what I can ask to uncle google.

Ps: The source image files are very big - like 5000x5000px so I cant only moving uvs with one big image.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why so complicated? Can't you add the images as a sequence and then just keyframe? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to make a 2d puppet with 8 handcrafted sides. And I need to switch with slider every view. And every view has its own rig. (head, torso, legs, hands .. etc)

Comment: I haven't done it before but I'm sure you could achieve this with drivers somehow - this answer may get you close... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57732/increase-transparency-in-animation-for-all-materials

Comment: Name all of the images with the same name and a sequence of numbers and map the image sequence as a texture. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay/61339#61339

Comment: Also please specify what render engine you are using.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I can use both cycle and blender render, because its research if the blender can handle this task. I trying to make the puppet and then automatization the processes for changing source files > to changle puppet character. Its little bit complex task, but step by step i am trying to solve all the problems what I found. Now its the "transparency" problem :)