# Rendering Empties

Tags: rendering, objects

So I've tried to use blender to make an intro for a few of my youtube videos, but the images I want to use only come up as empties which aren't rendered, so is there a way to turn an empty image into something render-able, or render empties at all, without losing the keyframes that I've made. Also I'm fairly new at this, so try and simplify your answers

Comment: Please place an informative screen capture with your question.  3D View window and outliner window. Think about what you need to present in the screen capture and say in words to make it easier for others to understand your question.  IMHOIIHO your question can be made clearer.  Your question can be improved.

Comment: Any plane can have a texture placed on it.  Blender is designed to be able to transfer keyframes to another object.  [Empty] object keyframes can be assigned to a plane with a texture.  You may need to search here at BSE on the techniques mentioned.  Please specify Blender Render or Cycles render.  In general I do not think of Blender as something simple.  There is always something new to understand and something changing.  By empty I mean the Empty object provided by blender.  Please confirm that meaning.

Answer (score 3):

[By definition](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45848/599), empties will not appear in the render.

If I understand correctly and you've already animated the empties around, try importing the images as texture planes (the [*import images as planes*](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images) addon bundled with blender is useful for doing this quickly).

The quickest way to make the planes follow the already-animated empties is probably just to *Parent* them. Select the plane, then the empty, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.