# Mirror modifier: Mirroring does not come out right

Tags: modifiers, mirror

In the red lines, that's my object I want to mirror. But as you can see, the mirroring does not come out right. It's not even a mirrored object of what mine originally looks like. How do I get this right?

Playing around with the merge limit didn't really change it either. It still cuts a part from the original one or overlaps it.

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding an empty at the centerpoint/line where you want to mirror to take place and then selecting it as the Mirror object in the modifier?

Comment: how do i add an empty and what is that?

Comment: [What is empty](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45848/what-is-an-empty). In general empty is just another way, while first way assumes placing origin point as needed. In this case origin point of the object is placed wrongly.

Comment: The mirror modifier mirrors from the object's origin, unless specified in the "Mirror Object" field. Move your object's origin to the object's corner, or add an empty in that corner and use that empty as the Mirror Object.