# Animate text as TEXT

Tags: python, animation, scripting, text-object

I have recently bought this plugin [IK-TextEffects](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/10/05/blender-market-ik-text-effects-add/)
as i really needed to animate text as text (my client wanted to see the animation, but he hasn't yet the final version of text) - but I was very disappointed as you need to BAKE the text in this plugin. So there is no point in this plugin as it's much easier to just animate a text witch is converted to a mesh.
My question IS:
Is it possible to make this kind of thing in Blender AT ALL? Is it possible to write a plugin for this very needful feature for motion design? If it's possible I will find a way to write a plugin for this - this is a must have feature for a professional workflow!

Comment: Of course it's possible. You would probably want to make the script by automatically adding keyframes and curves based on the position of objects and text characters rather than baking it, thus sounding more logical and efficient. See here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/58877/23798

Comment: The [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation-nodes) addon can [manipulate and animate text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li7R01PyXuI) objects.

Comment: Thnx, now I see it's possible. The problem with animation node add-on that it's so difficult to learn to use it. It's like learning new program from scratch. It's not very convenient to start playing with this than you have a dead line for a project...