# Align text on the inside of a circle

Tags: modeling, text-object

I'm trying to create a round object similar to a coin, where there are two text strings, one **above** the head - referred to here as the **top text** - and the other **below** the head - referred to as the **bottom text** (take an American quarter for example). Both the top text and the bottom text are right side up when the head is positioned properly, so they are both easy to read without rotating the coin.

Assuming that both text objects are aligned along a circle (**follow** a circle in Blender parlance), the top text must have the bottom of its characters toward the center of the circle, while the bottom text must have the top of its characters toward the center of the circle.

I can create and center easily the top text, by telling the text object to follow the circle and then rotating around the z axis depending on the length of the text. But I can't figure out how to create the bottom text. Without any other processing, round text rotated to the bottom will be upside down. I tried to turn the original text either upside down or right-to-left **before** rotating around the z axis, but after the final rotation I obtain the same result - the text is upside down and right-to-left.

I can't figure out a way to create this text that is right side up and has the top of its characters pointing to the center of the guiding circle. Has anyone done something like this? Is there maybe another way to do it?
(Note: the title line is slightly misleading but I used it for brevity - I don't necessarily care to have the bottom text **inside** the guiding circle, it can be on the outside as long as it is right side up and can be read naturally, just like the bottom text on an American quarter.)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32383/how-can-i-align-a-text-object-to-curve-without-deformation/32389#32389 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45764/how-to-text-sliding-out-of-a-circle-2d/45771#45771 and a lot more results if you use the search  box at the top: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=text+on+curve

Comment: I think what you're after is the "curve" modifier.

Comment: I have the same issue. Curve modifier deforms the text, I need to use "Text on curve" for this but I can't get the text the way he's describing. I think it might have to do with the origin.

Answer (score 1):

This has probably been solved a long time ago. But I just encountered this problem now and stumbled on the answer somehow.

If you want text to appear on the inside of the circle, you have to enter Edit mode and transform the bezier curve 180 deg along the x axis.